# How to make sure background stretches horizontal?

Tags: html, css, background

Here is my website

http://albuquerqueautomotiveservice.com/

but I coded it in my old computer and its monitor is rather squared then widescreen.

I just noticed in my laptop the right side of the page is gray.

How can I make sure it stretches only horizontally?

```
  body {
        background:#333 url(bg.jpg) no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        font-family:Arial;
        cursor: url(images/wrench.cur);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) is for:

```
background-size: cover;
```

---

If you support IE < 9, you'll have to use [their proprietary filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/path/to/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/path/to/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

---

Another option for IE would be to have the image as an actual `img` tag in your HTML:

```
<img src="/path/to/bg.jpg" class="page-background" />
```

Then use this piece of code in your CSS:

```
.page-background {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - True. In IE8 you should use their `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stretching why don't you just center your page?

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">

</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
 body 
 {
    background:#333 url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    font-family:Arial;
    cursor: url(images/wrench.cur);
 }

 #wrap
 { 
   width: 1250px; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
 }
```

Comment: My bad you would need to have width:1250px

Comment: it doesnt work any way, i just want the background to fit automatically horizontally

Comment: You may have to center your background image by adding 'center' to it then it should work.

Comment: Also by stretching you are making the top red portion of the site drop down on wider screens and you are distorting the image. I changed my answer, it should work now.